# Rotate or flip the square image in cocos2d

Tags: iphone, cocos2d-iphone, rotation, flip

Assume that one square image is for showing road. Now In  my game I have to flip this square image on Y axis so that it looks like road and person can walk on that road. I want this type of rotation.

But I want the same rotation in cocos2d then how I have to do it?

Thanks for help

Comment: did you make sprite with the image.

Comment: Do you want to flip the image on the X or Y axis? or rotate the image?

Answer (score 3):

I don't completely understand what you want to do, but I'll do my best here :)

You could use the flipX or flipY properties of a CCSprite

E.X.

```
CCSprite *sprite = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"file.png"];
sprite.position = position;
sprite.flipX = YES;
[self addChild:sprite];
```

or you could use a rotate action as Anish said.

Hope that helped.

Answer (score 2):

[Rotating Turrets in Cocos2D](http://www.raywenderlich.com/692/rotating-turrets)

Answer (score 1):

Try like this...

```
CCRotateBy *rot = [CCRotateBy actionWithDuration: 2 angle: 720];
[sprite runAction:rot];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
CCSprite *sprite = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"file.png"];
sprite.rotation = 45;
```

Answer (score 0):

I Flip CCSprite at Y axis like that in android...

```
CCSprite sprite=CCSprite.sprite("icon.png");
CCIntervalAction a = (CCIntervalAction)CCOrbitCamera.action(2, 1, 0, 0, 360, 0, 0);
addChild(sprite,1);
sprite.runAction(CCRepeatForever.action(a));
```